# Polymer 2 - Slot Testing

Tags: polymer-2.x, web-component-tester

I am running through some test suites, but the trouble is the test assertions are coming back negative because I cannot seem to access the pulled through content of the slot!

Basically looking for some resources and guidance on polymer 2 testing practices for slotted content

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might help to assert the contents of slots:

```
    var slots = this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll("slot")
    for (var i = 0, len = slots.length; i < len; i++) {
        console.log("slot: ", slots[i].assignedNodes());
        if (slots[i].assignedNodes().length != 0) {
            // assert something
...
```

This queries the slots of the shadowRoot and iterates them. With assignedNodes you get the contents of the respective slot.